# The Euler-Maruyama uses timestep Dt multiple of a step size dt

Tags: matlab

I wonder if you could help me with this?
 why the Euler-Maruyama uses timestep Dt multiple of a step size   of the increment dt for the Brownian path ?

http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/em.m

```
%EM  Euler-Maruyama method on linear SDE
%
% SDE is  dX = lambda*X dt + mu*X dW,   X(0) = Xzero,
%      where lambda = 2, mu = 1 and Xzero = 1.
%
% Discretized Brownian path over [0,1] has dt = 2^(-8).
% Euler-Maruyama uses timestep R*dt.

randn('state',100)
lambda = 2; mu = 1; Xzero = 1;    % problem parameters
T = 1; N = 2^8; dt = T/N;         
dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(1,N);         % Brownian increments
W = cumsum(dW);                   % discretized Brownian path 

Xtrue = Xzero*exp((lambda-0.5*mu^2)*([dt:dt:T])+mu*W); 
plot([0:dt:T],[Xzero,Xtrue],'m-'), hold on

R = 4; Dt = R*dt; L = N/R;        % L EM steps of size Dt = R*dt
Xem = zeros(1,L);                 % preallocate for efficiency
Xtemp = Xzero;
for j = 1:L
   Winc = sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j)); 
   Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*lambda*Xtemp + mu*Xtemp*Winc;
   Xem(j) = Xtemp;
end

plot([0:Dt:T],[Xzero,Xem],'r--*'), hold off
xlabel('t','FontSize',12)
ylabel('X','FontSize',16,'Rotation',0,'HorizontalAlignment','right')

emerr = abs(Xem(end)-Xtrue(end))
```

Comment: This question may be off-topic as it appears to be about the math rather than about programming. However, I'm not completely clear on what the question actually is. Are you trying to understand the Euler-Maruyama method from this code? I'd suggest really reading at [D.J Higham's excellent paper](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~cox/stoch/dhigham.pdf) for which this code was made. Are you asking why `Dt = 4*dt`? Well, it's just to show the effect of step size. Change `R` to `1` and see what happens.

Comment: No I'm not, I already understand this method through D.J Higham's paper and i read another document they said that " For convenience, we shall choose the step size in the Euler-Maruyama scheme" it's not question of math but i wonder why for the convenience  ?